# I need help translating the inscription on this vase

Tags: translation, traditional-characters

I need help translating this inscription so I can hopefully date the vase.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: 春风X柳花开日 微雨X晴紫华X
辛X之冬
x青XX
Can't figure out what are the other ones..

Answer (score 0):

春風拂柳花開日，微雨初晴紫華飛

for the date, 辛丑 means the year is 1841, 1901, or 1961. According to the tiny slice of the paint, it might be dated 1961.

Comment: So it's not a tiny slice of paint, it's a slightly faded makers mark I believe. I can add a close up photo

Comment: Also just to clarify all the characters are under glaze if that makes a difference...

Comment: no, I don't think so. All characters should be underglaze for most of the Chinese vases. To be honest,  the real date matters.

Comment: The 拂 does not seem to appear in the picture, only 撫. Sorry for commenting as editing requires a more-than-6-character change.

Comment: @XinShiyu Yes, you're right - there is one extra character. I have modified the answer. But I prefer 拂 over 撫, as in Chinese 拂 is more proper to describe the situation that the sprint breeze gently brushed the willow.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be 春風撫拂柳花開日，微雨初晴紫華飛

Comment: The 拂 does not seem to appear in the picture, only 撫. Sorry for commenting as editing requires a more-than-6-character change.